# Make a pagination using JQuery after getting data from api.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, pagination

Here is my codes-

**client.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title></title>
<style>
    #show{
        background:red;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<?php 
<div id="show"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#show').load('api.php')
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**api.php**

```
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'ajax01');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$result = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM variables");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['name'] . '<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

These codes are giving me the results like-

[Result of above codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW61w.jpg)

I am getting the values from database and it is fetching all the data. Therefore, I need a pagination with these value. Need help.

Comment: Please explain *I need a pagination with these value.*. What kind of pagination you want? Also, what's the point of using `setInterval()` and `load()` function? Use a simple AJAX request instead.

Comment: `setInterval()` is not an issue `load()`is calling the result of [api.php] I want a pagination that will show only one value and next page will show another. Please check the image attached with this post which is showing two results but I want one and another one in next page.

Comment: What do you mean by *next page*? Do you want to fetch the next result in the next call to `load()` function?

Comment: I mean second result will show after click on `next>`

Comment: I've given an answer below. Hopefully this is resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments,

> I want a pagination that will show only one value and next page will show another...second result will show after click on next>

There are few things you need to consider here,

- Instead of `setInterval()` and `load()` functions, simply use an AJAX request to implement your pagination functionality
- Use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because that will help you in preventing SQL injection. Also, read about how you can [prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Based on these above points and your below comments, **the solution** would be like this:

**client.php:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title></title>
<style>
    #show{
        background:red;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="show">
    <?php

        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'ajax01');
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        // prepare query statement
        if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM variables LIMIT 0, 1")){
            // execute statement
            $stmt->execute();

            // bind result variables
            $stmt->bind_result($name);

            // fetch values
            $stmt->fetch();

            // display name and pagination link
            if(isset($name) && !empty($name)){
                echo $name . '<br />';
                ?>
                <div id='link-div' style='background-color:#ffffff'>
                    <a href='' class='showmore' id='1'>Next&nbsp;&nbsp;&raquo;</a>
                </div>
                <?php
            }

            // close statement
            $stmt->close();
        }

    ?>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click','.showmore',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var offset = $(this).attr('id');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'api.php',
                cache: 'false',
                data: {offset: offset},

                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#link-div').html('<span>Loading...</span>');
                },

                success: function(data){
                    $('#link-div').remove();
                    $('#show').html(data);
                },

                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    // error
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**api.php:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['offset'])){
        $offset = $_POST['offset'];
        $prev = $offset - 1;  // Previous link in the pagination series
        $next = $offset + 1;  // Next link in the pagination series
        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'ajax01');
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        // prepare query statement
        if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(name) FROM variables")){
            // execute statement
            $stmt->execute();

            // bind result variables
            $stmt->bind_result($total_rows);

            // fetch values
            $stmt->fetch();

            // close statement
            $stmt->close();
        }

        // prepare query statement
        if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM variables LIMIT ?, 1")){
            // bind parameter
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $offset);

            // execute statement
            $stmt->execute();

            // bind result variables
            $stmt->bind_result($name);

            // fetch values
            $stmt->fetch();

            // display name and pagination link
            if(isset($name) && !empty($name)){
                echo $name . '<br />';
                ?>
                <div id='link-div' style='background-color:#ffffff'>
                    <?php
                        if($offset > 0){
                            ?>
                            <a href='' class='showmore' id='<?php echo $prev; ?>'>&laquo;Prev&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                            <?php
                        }
                        if($offset < $total_rows - 1){
                            ?>
                            <a href='' class='showmore' id='<?php echo $next; ?>'>Next&nbsp;&nbsp;&raquo;</a>
                            <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }

            // close statement
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: +1 but after clicking on `next>` a `<previous` link will appear and first value will not be shown (just second value will be shown) and after clicking on `<previous` the second value will not be shown (I mean _hour_) and `next>` link will appear. But still really thanks for you answer.

Comment: @user3311692 I've updated my answer. Please *upvote* and *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: "Thanks" again just one more question is it possible to hide `next>` if there is no value to show (such as with second value there is a `next>` link, there is no need of it cause there is no value to show)

Comment: @user3311692 I've further updated my answer, now it should work fine for you.